# how to show closest div on hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

i want to hover over a child element for it to show the NEAREST footer div on tumblr.

```
<div class="entry">
{block:Posts}
<div class="container">
{block:Text}{/block:Text}
{block:Photo}{/block:Photo}
{block:Text}{/block:Text}
</div>
<div class="footer"></div>
{/block:Posts}
</div>
```

the footer class is to be hidden but i want it so that when i hover over any one of the post type, only the footer of that post shows.

example :

i hover over my text post about something, it'll show the footer of THAT post specifically!

any help would be appreciated!

edit : i think my circumstances weren't properly explained so i updated!

Comment: use jquery next()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a css rule that conditionally hides the two, so long as the one is not hovered.

```css
.one:not(:hover) + .two {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">hi</div>
<div class="two">this</div>

<div class="one">is</div>
<div class="two">an</div>

<div class="one">example</div>
<div class="two">code</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You really do not need JavaScript when a simple CSS hover and next sibling selector can show it.

```css
.two {
   display: none;
}

.one:hover + .two {
  display: block;
}

/* If you want it to stay open if you are on the other div*/
.two:hover {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">hi</div>
<div class="two">this</div>

<div class="one">is</div>
<div class="two">an</div>

<div class="one">example</div>
<div class="two">code</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery `next()` function and `mouseneter`, `mouseleave` to simulate hover effect:

**CSS**:

```
.one {}
.two {display:none;}
```

**javascript**:

```
jQuery('.one').on('mouseenter', function(){
    $(this).next('.two').css('display', 'block');
});

jQuery('.one').on('mouseleave', function(){
    $(this).next('.two').css('display', 'none');
});
```

[**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/rdvak2qo/)